# Redis sync fails. Redis copy keys and values works

Tags: caching, redis

I have two redis instances both running on the same machine on win64. The version is the one from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis with no amendments and the binaries are running as per download from github (ie version 2.6.12).

I would like to create a slave and sync it to the master. I am doing this on the same machine to ensure it works before creating a slave on a WAN located machine which will take around an hour to transfer the data that exists in the primary.

However, I get the following error:

```
[4100] 15 May 18:54:04.620 * Connecting to MASTER...
[4100] 15 May 18:54:04.620 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
[4100] 15 May 18:54:04.620 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
[4100] 15 May 18:54:04.620 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...

[4100] 15 May 18:54:28.364 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 2147483647 bytes from master
[4100] 15 May 18:55:05.772 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
[4100] 15 May 18:55:14.508 # Short read or OOM loading DB. Unrecoverable error, aborting now.
```

The only way I can sync up is via a mini script something along the lines of :

```
import orm.model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = orm.model.caching.Redis(**{"host":"source_host","port":6379})
    dest = orm.model.caching.Redis(**{"host":"source_host","port":7777})
    ks = src.handle.keys()
    for i,k in enumerate(ks):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print i, "%2.1f %%" % ( (i * 100.0) / len(ks))
        dest.handle.set(k,src.handle.get(k))
```

where orm.model.caching.* are my middleware cache implementation bits (which for redis is just creating a self.handle instance variable).

Firstly, I am very suspicious of the number in the receiving bytes as that is 2^32-1 .. a very strange coincidence. Secondly, OOM can mean out of memory, yet I can fire up a 2nd process and sync that via the script but doing this via redis --slaveof fails with what appears to be out of memory. Surely this can't be right?

redis-check-dump does not run as this is the windows implementation.

Unfortunately there is sensitive data in the keys I am syncing so I can't offer it to anybody to investigate. Sorry about that.

I am definitely running the 64 bit version as it states this upon startup in the header.

I don't mind syncing via my mini script and then just enabling slave mode, but I don't think that is possible as the moment slaveof is executed, it drops all known data and resyncs from scratch (and then fails).

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this error earlier, but the latest bits from 2.8.4 seem to have resolved it https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.8.4_msopen

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about looking at the 2.8.4_msopen branch as I thought it might not be stable .. but will try that anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately no dice :-( .... It behaves better but I still get the same interesting number for bytes being copied and then a complete crash.

Comment: hmm, what's the maxmemory set for the both master and slave instances?